# Tenor sax octave pads: both open or both closed

Tags: saxophone

I play Tenor sax (Kessler Custom), and something has been bugging me: are both of the octave pads supposed to be open or closed at the same time?

If you play C# (no keys pressed), both keys are closed.  Pressing the LH thumb key raises the neck octave pad.  Playing a G drops the neck octave pad and raises the bypass one on the main body of the horn (all expected).
*While* transitioning between the neck octave pad and the bypass one, should both pads be opened or closed?  The ideal is probably to have them switch at the same instant, but that's not quite possible.  On my sax they're open (briefly), and I think it's contributing to my squeaking.
Or perhaps I should investigate the LH ring key more...

Answer (score 2):

> The ideal is probably to have them switch at the same instant

Correct.  This is a somewhat complicated mechanism, and it falls out of adjustment pretty easily, especially on cheaper instruments which the Kessler is.  I can't provide any further diagnosis from this info, but any good shop should do a free diagnostic.